# No internet on VMWare workstation 12 player

Tags: vmware

My Host OS is Windows 10 and I have installed VMware workstaion 12 player. On Guest VMWare Machine I have installed OS Windows 2008 Server R2.

I used to get internet on Guest(VmWare) Machine , Now it is not coming. When I checked "Local Area Connection" i found the message "Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding"
Then I followed the steps mentioned in below link. Still there is no internet.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2779064/your-computer-appears-to-be-correctly-configured-but-the-device-or-res.

Thanks and Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Try to change NAT in network connection in your vmware settings.

If it works do below configuration to work it on bridge network. Go to Virtual Network Editor and do configure like in this image

[image: VirtualNetworkEditor]